# Is there any rule that says you can't play with two rackets in badminton?

Tags: rules, badminton, racket

Is there any rule that says you can't play with two rackets in badminton?

That is, one racket in each hand, so for example you don't have to hit a backhand; you can just do forehands.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike International Tennis Federation (ITF) which specifically bans using more than one racket under the rule 4. THE RACKET, Case 5:

> [TENNIS RULES]
> Is a player allowed to use more than one racket at any time during
> play?
>
> Decision: **No**.

Badminton World Federation (BWF) laws don't state anything specific on using more than one racket. However, like ITF, they use the singular form of the noun **racket** in the laws, based on which we can safely assume using more than one racket is prohibited.

One more thing to consider is would it really help to use two rackets? If you play with two rockets, it will be more difficult to serve effectively (you need to note there is a rule on **Service**, too) and it might injure your hands when you try to dive to receive a shuttle.

Comment: perhaps the fact that  tennis has a specific prohibition for it, indicates that they thought that without that specific prohibition, the tennis rules wouldn't clearly prohibit more than one racket.. Thus likewise that'd be the case with badminton, though badminton doesn't have a specific prohibition, so it's not clearly / far from clearly, prohibited.

Comment: @barlop How can you serve holding two rackets in tennis?

Comment: you don't have to hold both to serve, you could have a sheeth like people have for a sword, and whip out the second racket when there is time. So if in badminton you're returning a serve you could hold both.  Or if a shot is a high clear coming at you then you could whip out the second racket from the sheeth, or better, whip it out while your partner is going for a clear, there's lots of time there.

Comment: @barlop Yeah. A few more distractions for a player. That's why they don't use two rackets.

Comment: But would you agree that the fact that the tennis people thought it necessary to prohibit two rackets in tennis, suggests that without that prohibition, it'd be allowed or not prohibited. And why wouldn't that logic apply to badminton?

Comment: @barlop Now, I see what's confused you. Why would no badminton player use two rackets if they think they can play better with two rackets? Do table tennis laws have anything about using two rackets?

Comment: Well, there are different possible answers as to why no badminton player has tried playing with two rackets. One is that to do so would go against convention, and they haven't trained for it and the first people to try it would be taking a risk because if after training with it it turns out that they played better with one racket, then they would have wasted some of their training.  And they might also be socially conditioned to not play with two because they don't want to look weird. Clearly the tennis law people thought some might want to and thus thought to add a prohibition against it.

Comment: @barlop Shall we stop here? I think we had enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but can use either hand effectively. The difficulty I see, is in anticipating a return shot your stance will be set, with one raised racket.

From that point you are restricted in what you can deploy in a fraction of a second. If your body is committed to one racket before your opponent smashes, that's your best option. I have occasionally switched hands in play, more to give my predominant arm a rest than be more competitive.

The other difficulty of having a racket in your free hand is it will get in the way all the time, as that arm is used extensively for counterbalancing both for balance and strength.

There's also no real argument for doing forehand shots all the time, back-hands can be equally powerful with practice.

Comment: you  write " in anticipating a return shot your stance will be set, with one raised racket"  <-- you anticipate a return shot that can come in either direction, that is, to your left, or to your right,  and you raise both rackets in anticipation of a next shot on one or the other side.   Ready to hit a shot on your left hand side, or on your right hand side. Why only raise one racket?

Comment: And putting aside that lots of people have  a weak backhand.. even if they'd practised their backhand,   Is your "backhand smash" as strong as your forehand smash?

Answer (score -1):

> Not specifically but you can deduce the answer is you are allowed 1 racket per person.

**4.3 The racket:**

4.3.1:

[The racket] shall be free of attached objects and protrusions, other than those used solely and specifically to limit or prevent wear and tear, or vibration, or to distribute weight, or to secure the handle by cord to the player's ***hand***, and which are reasonable in size and placement for such purposes

> Also:

**EQUIPMENT COMPLIANCE**

The International Badminton Federation shall rule on any question of whether any racket, shuttle or equipment or any prototype used in the playing of Badminton complies with the specifications. Such ruling may be undertaken on the Federation's initiative or on application by any party with a bona fide interest, including any player, technical official, equipment manufacturer or Member Association or member thereof.

> I imagine the Federation would rule this illegal.

Comment: well, 4.3.1 is completely irrelevant

Comment: And re equipment compliance, playing with two rackets does not mean that a racket doesn't meet the specifications, one thing has nothing to do with the other.